# Finding area of a spheroid

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, area

Let $M=\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb{R}^3 : (x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 + (z/c)^2 = 1\}$. Find $\text{vol}_2(M) = \int_M 1 dS$.

**My attempt:**

The map $$\Phi:(0,\pi)\times (0,2\pi)\to \Bbb{R}^3\\ \qquad (\varphi, \theta)\mapsto (a\cos\theta \sin \varphi, a \sin \theta \sin \varphi, b \cos \varphi)$$
is a global chart for $M$ except on a 2-dimensional null-set.
We have $$g(\varphi, \theta) = D \phi(\varphi, \theta) ^T \cdot D \phi(\varphi, \theta) = a^2 \sin^2 \varphi \cdot ( a^2 \cos^2 \varphi + b^2 \sin^2 \varphi),$$ so 
$$ \text{vol}_2(M) = \int_M 1 dS = \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{g(\varphi, \theta})\,\, d\theta d\varphi = 2\pi \int_0^{\pi} a\sin \varphi \sqrt{ a^2 \cos^2 \varphi + b^2 \sin^2 \varphi} \,\,d\varphi$$

which I haven't been able to solve.

Is there a nicer way global chart for $M$ that allows us to compute the integral in the end?

Comment: Perhaps the last integral could be solved using $\sin^2\varphi=1-\cos^2\varphi$ adn then using substitution $u=\cos\varphi$...?